# Encrypt decrypt DynamoDB Data based on client Auth

Tags: encryption, amazon-dynamodb, aws-secrets-manager

I have a use case of users and group. Data gets saved into dyanmodb. I am struggling with securing the data.

I have user and group in Cognito. Data is saved/retrieved via DynamoDB, but I want to encrypt the data so that even I don't see it or even I can't modify it but all the users within the group can view it. The hash and range key are fine, no need to encrypt but can work if encrypted.

Imagine there are users like user1, 2, 3 ,4 and group 1.
User 1,2,3 are in group 1. Now only User 1 can modify his data but User 2 and 3 can view it. User3 and 4 can't view or write. I can have this as an application logic. But I want to encrypt the data so even as the Admin of AWS account I can't modify it. Ofcourse I will be able to delete it but thats fine, user will anyway know this

Is that possible?